# Как можно реализовать закрытие текущей вкладки спустя 3 секунды после входа на страницу?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Как можно реализовать закрытие текущей вкладки (страницы) спустя 3 секунды после входа на страницу?

Comment: Никак. Браузер не даст закрыть вкладку открытую не скриптом. Как минимум без клика пользователя

Comment: @Matel а продемонстрировать?

Comment: что именно продемонстрировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function closeTab() {
  window.close();
}

setTimeout(closeTab, 3000);
```

Comment: Не работает почему - то

Comment: попробуйте так `open(location, '_self').close();` вместо `window.close();`

Comment: страница просто обновляется..

Comment: Кстати,в эдже все ок,в мозилле или хроме - не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.close();
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Не работает почему - то